# AngularJS: How to dynamically initialize a controller in a template from within another controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-templates

I would like `ChildCtrl` to be initialized only when the button above it is clicked. how is that possible?

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <button>CLICK TO INIT CHILD CTRL</button>
    <div class="child-container">
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl" ng-include="'templates/child.html'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easy, use ng-if:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <button ng-click='loadChild=true'>CLICK TO INIT CHILD CTRL</button>
    <div class="child-container" ng-if='loadChild'>
        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl" ng-include="'templates/child.html'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`ng-if` directive does not load the DOM unless the expression is `true`.

Comment: @YossiShasho keep in mind that `ng-if` creates an isolated scope. If `ParentCtrl` added `thing` to it's scope, then that is now accessed as `$parent.thing` inside `ChildCtrl.scope` because of `ng-if`.